# Getting specific values from mySQL database stored on web in android

Tags: android

In my app I am having local Sqlite database and also other mySQL database saved on web (currently using localhost). I want to fetch specific values from mySQL database and that values to be updated in local Sqlite  database.

In return like same some values from local Sqlite database to MySQL database on web(or localhost).

As you know it's easy for saving data in android and I did that stuff but getting problem while implementing

ANDROID-->WEB-->ANDROID   interaction if you have did it before or having any idea,any links,or sample code please help me on this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try it on `localhost` then the link below is good.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: @ LAKSH It's good one but I am having local database Sqlite and want to update it bye fetching some specific values from mySQL database which is stored on localhost. I need just some specific values not all the data.

Comment: If you go through the whole code carefully, then you will find that in the `EditProductActivity.java` you can fetch all the column data for a specific row. You can then accordingly fetch which data you want from that row.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanism you are trying to achieve like Android -> Web -> Android, can be achieved and explained here [check it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29943178/1878148).