# How to fetch particular values of record from SQL databse stored on server and update that values in SQLite database of android?

Tags: android, sql, web-services

In my application I am having database stored on the web server, I want to fetch particular values of record stored in SQL database. After getting that values want to update these values in the record stored in SQLite database of android.

Comment: what you have tried to achieve this.

Comment: what are you expecting ?

Comment: @ Imran and Sheldon....In my application am having some forms with details user will enter that details after saving, it will be saved in SQLite database of android tablet......Also having other screen with upload and download buttons....after Clicking upload button all the data should be saved in web server database and after clicking on download only respected updated values for corresponding records should be fetched and stored in SQLite database of android tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope of question is very broad can't answer in few lines, but can give you idea. For achieving above functionality there is no any such mechanism so that android client (like tablet/mobile) directly get connected to web servers. For making this happen you need to write web services at server side which will take request from android client, process it as per request types and returns the resulted processed data. You can consume this web response at client side and do operations like saving it in Sqlite database. Similarly you can sync local sqlite database with server via web services only. You can easily consume Restful web services using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).